# Combining 2 csv files based on same column using join

Tags: bash, csv, join, merge

I have been trying to combine two csv files with alphanumeric data based on the column names they share, so that I can perform something like a join over them using terminal.

Here's what I tried: (my first column of both the files are identical)

> join -t , -1 1 -2 1 file_1.csv file_2.csv > file_3.csv

The merge happens alright and my columns are combined but not in the format I want.

**Issue:**
The file_3 consists of lines from both the files, though separated by commas, but in separate lines.

Example:

```
     Columns from file_1
     ,Columns from file_2
     Row1 from file_1
     ,Row1 from file_2
     Row2 from file_1
     ,Row2 from file_2
```

What do I do to get the file_3 data in one single line for each row-merge? Any pointers to proceed would be appreciated.

file_1.csv: (sample data)

```
Id,Age,Employment,Education,Marital,Occupation,Income,Gender,Deductions,Hours,Adjusted
1,38,Private,College,Unmarried,Service,81838,Female,0,72,0  
2,35,Private,Associate,Absent,Transport,72099,Male,0,30,0  
3,32,Private,HSgrad,Divorced,Clerical,154676.74,Male,0,40,0
```

file_2.csv: (sample data)

```
Id,Adjusted,Predicted_Adjusted,Probability_0,Probability_1
1,0,0,0.952957896225136,0.0470421037748636 . 
2,0,0,0.973664421132328,0.0263355788676716 . 
3,0,0,0.966224074718457,0.0337759252815426
```

Erroneous join:

```
Id,Age,Employment,Education,Marital,Occupation,Income,Gender,Deductions,Hours,Adjusted
,Adjusted,Predicted_Adjusted,Probability_0,Probability_1
1,38,Private,College,Unmarried,Service,81838,Female,0,72,0
,0,0,0.952957896225136,0.0470421037748636
2,35,Private,Associate,Absent,Transport,72099,Male,0,30,0
,0,0,0.973664421132328,0.0263355788676716
3,32,Private,HSgrad,Divorced,Clerical,154676.74,Male,0,40,0
,0,0,0.966224074718457,0.0337759252815426
```

Expected output:
Every two lines is actually one row and so the expected output should not have the rows split into two, but should represent a homogenous merge of two csv files i.e file_1 and file_2

Comment: Are the files without windows line-endings `\r`? You can try `dos2unix file_1.csv` (I couldn't reproduce your output).

Comment: Thank you! This was the catch. Both my files had windows line-endings as you suspected. Used dos2unix and converted them to ASCII text and the join worked perfectly. Could you please post your advice as a separate answer below, so that I can "accept" it? :)

Comment: Would be good if you add small pieces of example data and your expected output from that data to the question.

Comment: @hek2mgl Thank you for pointing that out. I have added it as per your advice so that it may help others who face similar issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are the files with windows line-endings `\r`?
You can try `dos2unix file_1.csv` and `dos2unix file_2.csv` ?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
join -t , -1 1 -2 1 file_1.csv file_2.csv|paste -d' ' - - > file_3.csv
```

Comment: Tried as advised. It's the same. file_3 still shows the data in separate rows

Comment: Do you want everything in a single line?

Comment: Or just bunch 2 lines in 1 line

Comment: Bunch every 2 lines into 1 line. As seen in the example above, every set of two lines is actually one entire row. So, I'm trying trying to achieve the same result.

Comment: side-note: `-1 1 -2 1` could be just `-1`

Comment: @hek2mgl I see! I didn't know that. Thank you. So, it directly assumes the join is on the column 1 on both files?